# Most Supported Java Date/Time Class

Tags: android, calendar, localdate

I have an issue with date/time age calculations on Android Studio. I have used calander instance and it seemed to work for the most part but every now and then it seems to be Inaccurate.

I switched to LocalDate which looks way cleaner but, as far as I can tell through my research is only supported by API 26 and higher. I think Joda Time has the same issue.

My question is this: What is the best method to calculate the elapsed time between two dates that is the most accurate (factoring in leap years, months with different number of days, etc) and is supported by lower API versions (ie 17 and up)?

I have been researching and it appears that the answer may be the basic calander instance but then I come back to reliability and accuracy issue. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe using 3rd-party libraries (ThreetenABP, Joda-Time for Android or Time4A)?

Comment: Thank you Meno, yeah I had the same issue with Joda-Time but I will try it again...

Comment: For age calculations I would recommend: a) ThreetenABP (backport of java.time) => `ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(LocalDate, LocalDate)` or b) Time4A (bigger lib with more features) => `CalendarUnit.YEARS.between(PlainDate, PlainDate)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library in work with earlier versions of Android.

```
Period.between(
    LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JUNE , 23 ) , 
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( “Europe/Paris” ) )
)
```

## Use *java.time*

The original date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java were well-intentioned but are an awful ugly confusing mess. Always **avoid `Date`, `Calendar`**, etc.

Joda-Time was an amazing industry-leading effort to make a serious robust date-time framework. Its principal author, Stephen Colebourne, went on to use the lessons learned there to produce its successor, the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 & 9, defined by JSR 310. The **Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode**, and migration to java.time is advised.

Much of the ***java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7** in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project. That project includes a utility class for converting to/from the legacy types so your new code may interoperate with old existing code. Further adapted for earlier Android in the *ThreeTenABP* project.

For example, on the Java platform you would call:

```
java.time.LocalDate localDate = java.time.LocalDate.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 ) ; // January 23rd, 2018.
```

…whereas on early Android using the *ThreeTen-Backport*/*ThreeTenABP* projects you would call:

```
org.threeten.bp.LocalDate localDate = org.threeten.bp.LocalDate.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 ) ; // January 23rd, 2018.
```

## Span of time

To calculate elapsed time as a span of time unattached to the timeline, use either:

- `Period` for years, months, days
- `Duration` for hours, minutes, seconds, and fractional second in nanoseconds.

---

More simply put…

## About *java.time*

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the *java.time* classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Basil, thank you... the problem I am running into is with the LocalDate.of(year, month, day) that is where I get the error on the "of" saying that it requires API 26 or higher... I am still looking into it though. I don't want to go back to the Date, Calendar... etc..

Comment: @ErrolNiel An implementation of *java.time* (JSR 310) was added to only the latest versions of Android. If your project is set to build for earlier versions of Android, you have no `LocalDate` class available, and thus a compiler error for calling `LocalDate.of`. As an alternative, you must **add a library to your project** as a substitute for the absent java.time classes. That library is *ThreeTen-Backport*, packaged as *ThreeTenABP* for Android. Instead of calling `java.time.LocalDate.of`, you call `org.threeten.bp.LocalDate.of`. Use `import` statements such as `import org.threeten.bp.* ;`

Comment: Thank you Basil, I will try that. I will look up the necessary imports for ThreeTenABP.